# Can somebody tell me where the process table/Queue for running process is maintained in linux kernel source?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I just wanted to understand the concept of how the running process / queued process are maintained by linux kernel.Please give pointers to the kernel source where it is being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done by the scheduler and the code is found in a bunch of files. Start from linux-source/kernel/sched.c and trace your path from there.

Concepts of how task scheduling is done is a bit complex under linux since it actually supports several different schedulers. So to start with the understanding have a read of linux-source/Documentation/sched-design-CFS.txt which is the design of the "Completely Fair Scheduler"

## Data Structure maintaining the tasks

In 2.6.x and 3.x kernels the tasks are maintained in various run-queues. The run queue structure `struct rq` maintains the basic run queue. Then there are run-queue bits for each of the specific schedulers. For example cfs_rq (sched.c) maintains the queue for CFS. The  `struct task_groups` (in sched.c linux/sched.h) and the task structure `struct task_struct` maintain the actual information on the tasks.

sched.c and sched.h have nothing but the related functions and structures.

Comment: thanks. I didn't go through the entire file. I would definitely go through the scheduler. But as of now, I am more concerned/interested in data structure/ data base / Queue whatever , which maintains the running process and queued process.

Comment: Okay. thanks for the information. I would go through those documents and files.